# Xamarin 115 error message

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I'm new in Xamarin. I make a mistake yesterday by adding new package without checked dependency and then I uninstalled the package.But After that I received message below.

I have tried uninstalled xamarin.forms package and installed again,clean solution and build solution but rebuild all failed.I don't know what mistake that I make.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears you have a typo in `HomePage.xaml`

Comment: I already checked but there no typo problem. Most error display "label not found","stacklayout not found" and others. Every time I opened the file,total amount of error increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

I tried many kind of method.Only this fixed my problem.

1. Unload the project
2. close Visual Studio and run back as Administrator.
3. reload the project
4. rebuild solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have to tried delete bin/obj and restart visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove bin and obj folders.
2. Restart Visual Studio.
3. Run Clean and Rebuild for solution.
4. Try run the your app